# EE and Store UPS Shipping Canada API

Tags: expresso-store, ups-shipping

I have a store on EE 2.9.0 with Store UPS shipping.

But I cannot reach Domestic Ground when the user has to choose his shipping mode.
I'm in Canada and need to ship in Canada but it looks like the extension is created for USA.

In the file on the extension I had:

```
    '03' => 'Domestic Ground',
    '12' => 'Domestic 3 Day Select',
    '01' => 'Domestic Next Day Air',
    '14' => 'Domestic Next Day Air Early AM',
    '13' => 'Domestic Next Day Air Saver',
    '02' => 'Domestic Second Day Air',
    '59' => 'Domestic Second Day Air AM',
    '11' => 'International Standard',
    '65' => 'International Saver',
    '07' => 'International Worldwide Express',
    '54' => 'International Worldwide Express Plus',
    '08' => 'International Worldwide Expedited',
```

But I talked with UPS Canada and they said Domestic Ground number 20

Has anybody the same problem before?

Comment: did you ever solve this? I am having issues in canada as well. A simple paperback book costs $170 to ship to the same postal code

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/8494)

Answer (score 0):

The UPS gateway is indeed for the US. You should be able to copy the plugin files and then update the service codes along with the API end points to match UPS Canada. If you need to have both the UPS US and Canada version live you would also need to change the namespacing accordingly